# use external sign-in with ASP.NET Core (Api) jwt in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to user external sign-in with `ASP.NET Core` (for example:  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter`) in my project with client `reactjs` and backend side `WebApi` (jwt)

do you have any idea is possible and if possible how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this particular guide?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/twitter-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0

EDIT 1.
Look at the parent page and work your way down. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Here is [SPA example in case you missed it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Security is a puzzle, it is up to you to learn the different components and put them together based on the architecture of your solution.

Comment: this link is not related my question. this link work for asp.net form/mvc not asp.net api and not have any related to SPA framework like reactjs

Comment: That is not correct @foadabd. You need to read the document, you will find a specific SPA example in the parent as well. Each of these documents covers only a component of the puzzle, you have to put them together.